# Search: what should the form page look like?

Tags: html

I'm new to html and am trying to implement a search function. I've created an input box and search buttons but I have no idea what the form page should look like. Please Help. Thank you!
Here's the code:

```
"<form name=MB method=\"POST\" action=\"formpage-->not sure what this page should look like">\n "
"<p align=MIDDLE>Search for Tokens: " + //Search Description 
"<input name=\"term\" type=\"text\" onkeypress=\"if(event.keyCode==13) " +
"document.MB.exact.click();\" size=30> </p> \n" + //Search Box
"\n<FONT FACE=\"Geneva,Arial,Helvetica,lucida sans,san-serif\"><STRONG>" + //search buttons
"<input name=\"exact\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Find Exact\"" +
"\n<input name=\"AND\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Find All Tokens\">" +
"\n<input name=\"OR\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Find Any Tokens\">" +
"\n</STRONG></FONT></TD>\n</TR>\n</TABLE>\n</form>\n"
```

PS the reaszon it's all in quotes is because its a java program that generates the html`enter code here`

Comment: Please post whatever code you have.

Comment: Can you give some more details? It isn't clear what question you are actually asking. For instance, you can post some code that you tried and explain why it is not doing what you expect it to so we can point out where the problem may be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty vague question but you probably want something like:

```
<form action="URL_FOR_SEARCH_HERE" method="GET">
<input type="text" name="query"/><br />
<input type="submit" value="Search"/>
</form>
```

(URL_FOR_SEARCH_HERE would be replaced by something like "/search.php", depending on what server-side technology you're using to do the actual search processing.)

Comment: so i guess what i really want to know is how do i utilize the server-side technology to do search processing?

Comment: That's a much bigger question; what kind of server-side technology do you have available?  You may want to close this question and start a new one ("how do I create a search box for my site using PHP?" or whatever the appropriate technology is).

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you are searching for as well. If you are searching through a database then your form should point to some code that executes a sql search function.